# Trying to serialize() a group of input fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to `serialize()` a group of input field data and am not getting anything in my logs. Can someone point me in the right direction? I have read the jQuery documentation on .seralize() and it "looks" like I am doing it right. Here is a fiddle roughly of what I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/GaY96/

Comment: You haven't loaded jQuery in your Fiddle, btw (although that's not the actual problem, see Arun's answer)

Comment: yes, i did. It's in the external resources in the left pane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.serialize()` uses `input` element's name, to serialize it. In your case it is missing.

```
<input name="unitname" type="text" value="test" placeholder="Unit Name" />
```

Also calling it in an non form element(other than form and input elements) [does not seems to be working](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/serialize-does-not-serialize-in-elements-other-than-forms). So try

```
var datastring = $(".editunitinfo :input").serialize();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PFJTe/)

Comment: I'm wrong `.serialize()` uses `input` not only in form , atleast now I know :) +1